# How to fix an incompatible type error

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two printf they are separate because one is doing a loop I am having trouble aligning one of the printf. I want it tho line up under friends.

**What is printing**

```
Member                     Friends             
Chi Cho                 Joe Blow
                 Jimmy Brown
Status: 

Joe Blow                 John Ko
Status: Coding like a friend

Tammy Joe                 Joe Johnson
Status: this is great

Bing Smith                 John Brown
Status: This sucks
```

**what I am trying to get**

```
Member                     Friends             
Chi Cho                    Joe Blow
                           Jimmy Brown
Status: 

Joe Blow                   John Ko
Status: Coding like a friend

Tammy Joe                  Joe Johnson
Status: this is great

Bing Smith                 John Brown
Status: This sucks
```

---

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i< profiles; i++)
    {
    String arrayName = face.get(i).getName();       
    String statusName = face.get(i).getStatus();

    LinkedList<String> linkName = face.get(i).getFriend();
    String realname ="";
   System.out.printf("%-20s", arrayName);

   for (String toname : linkName) {
        System.out.printf("%-20s", toname);
        System.out.println();
```

**Where the error is**

---

```
if (toname != linkName.size() - 1) {
            System.out.printf("%-20s", "");
            }
    }
```

---

```
    System.out.println("Status: " + statusName);
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are going to need the index of the item, don't use the fast enum syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its called `size()` in Lists :)
[check here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size())

Comment: This comes from the Collection interface. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#size%28%29

Comment: @TheLostMind so how would I implement that?

Comment: @TheLostMind but now i am getting incapable types with the array size and toname

Comment: @TheLostMind nevermind the person bellow did it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The above snippet would become this if you are using a list:

```
if (toname != arraylistName.get(arraylistName.size() - 1)) {
    System.out.printf("%-20s", "");
}
```